# Docker image: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, asp.net-core, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to run an ASP.NET Core 3.1 framework based app on an Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS) server using Docker container.

I created the following `docker-compose.yml` file to be able to run both `nginx-proxy` and `private_image_name` images on my server. Obviously,  `nginx-proxy` is a proxy server that will be the proxy that would route traffic coming from the web to my other running images. I followed the [article](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/host-multiple-websites-docker-nginx/) for the `nginx-proxy` setup.

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certificates:/etc/certificates

  private_image_name:
    image: private_image_name:latest
    container_name: private_image_name
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=sub.domain-example.com
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - 51736:80
      - 44344:443
    volumes:
      - storage:/storage
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certificates:/etc/certificates
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
volumes:
  storage:
  certificates:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
secrets:
  server.cert:
    file: ./server.cert
  server.key:
    file: ./server.key
```

Both `server.cert` and `server.key` files are stored in `/etc/certificates`. Both files were created using the following command

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 3650 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/L=SF/O=Docker-demo/CN=app.example.org" -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

I attempted to run both of my images by executing `docker-composer up`. However, the `nginx-proxy` came up with no issue and while `private_image_name` failed to run. The following is what I get when running the `private_image_name` attempts to start

```
**WARNING**: The APPDATA variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Recreating private_image ... done
Attaching to private_image
private_image    | crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
private_image    |       Unable to start Kestrel.
private_image    | System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
private_image    | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
private_image    | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
private_image    | Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
private_image    | To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
private_image    | For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
private_image    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
private_image    |    at private_image.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/private_image/Program.cs:line 17
private_image exited with code 139
```

The command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` works on Windows and macOS only.

**Question**

How can I fix this issue on the Ubuntu server? How can I correctly attach the SSL cert to the docker image?

Additionally, when I go to http://server-ip-address or http://sub.domain-example.com I get

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.17.5

And when I go to https://server-ip-address or https://sub.domain-example.com I get

> Unable to connect.

Answer (score 26):

As soon as you've setup the certificate in nginx, I see no sense enabling it in the asp.net core container as your docker network is going to be visible to public via nginx.

To disable Kestrel Https listening just remove 443 port from the following code:

```
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
```

Replace it with:

```
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
```

With .NET 8.0 container some breaking changes were introduced:

We also added the new `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` environment variable as a simpler alternative to `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. The new variable expects a semicolon delimited list of ports numbers, while the older variable expects a more complicated syntax.

Apps built using the older `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` API won't respect the new `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` environment variable. And now that `ASPNETCORE_URLS` is no longer set automatically, they'll switch to use a default URL of `http://localhost:5000`, rather than `http://*:80`, as formerly.

Detailed information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port

Comment: @user1007074 As soon as application is configured to use https, kestrel web server requires certificate to make it work. You can check documentation about this environment variable in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#server-urls

Comment: Together with the .NET 8 introduction, this behavior changed. Follow link to see details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port

Answer (score 9):

In my case the main issues was with `docker-compose.override.yml` file. Docker files were generated on Windows machine so the following lines were not correct for mac.

```
- ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
- ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

I had to replace them with the following lines:

```
- ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
- ~/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Final code for `docker-compose.override.yml` which worked:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project-api:
    image: project-api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5001:443"
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ~/.microsoft/usersecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Answer (score 8):

For the folks that came here because of a similar problem, this helped me to resolve an issue:

Clean the development certificates:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

Create a new one

```
dotnet dev-certs https -t
```

Comment: this step requires manual intervention with is not possible for docker. or is there a way to auto accept the prompt?

"Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate."

Comment: While I am not working in Docker at the moment so this might not help the OP, your "--clean" step helped me solve a development certificate issue I couldn't solve while testing a web api in Visual Studio. Thanks.